# 301 Redirect for ?Page_ID pages

Tags: .htaccess

I have an old Wordpress site that I have converted to a new Wordpress site. the problem is the old developer used page ids instead of changing the permalinks. I have to redirect an entire site of page ids to the actual new page names. I have found code to redirect any page id to the home page, but my client wants to have each page id match the new page I created. Could you let me know how to do this in .htaccess file if it's possible? Here's my .htaccess code so far. When I test this, it directs all the old pages to the home page:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} page_id=(.*)$
RewriteRule $ /? [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

THANK YOU!

Answer (score -1):

One thing you could do is to remove these two lines

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} page_id=(.*)$
RewriteRule $ /? [R=301,L]
```

from your .htaccess.

Login to your wordpress installation, go to

Settings → Permalinks → Common Settings

and choose

Custom Structure: /%postname%/

If you have many pages, posts **DO NOT USE THIS** if your WordPress version is < v.3.3